# Show current time on page in real ticks format using Rails and change with every second

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to display time on my page in real tics format like running on simple watch without

refresh the whole page.I am using rails 3.Give any idea

Comment: `setInterval(function () { console.log(new Date().toLocaleString()); }, 1000);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes interesting situation I think you should put your portion of display time in some partial and refresh it with jquery ajax call. So you need to refresh it with every second and also you can set frequency of that ajax call. Here is some code may be it help you.

Html code:

```
 <div class="time-rect-container">
   <%= render :partial => 'shared/time_portion' %>
 </div>
```

Code of partial of time_portion. It just shows time.

```
<h1>System Time</h1>

<div class="time-detail"><p><%=@time%></p></div>
```

Controller code:

```
def give_time

  @time = Time.now.strftime("%H:%M:%S ")

  render :partial => 'shared/time_portion'

end
```

And refresh this partial by jquery ajax call and I set frequency of it for one second and you can change.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {

        $('.time-rect-container').load('/dashboard/give_time');

    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Why would you use the backend to display this!? You could just use `new Date();...`

Comment: Where does the controller code go? Application_Controller.rb?

Comment: yes in application controller.rb. But you can kept it any other controller according to your need.

Comment: Bruno i would recommend you to search for some js plugin.

Answer (score 0):

[**JS Clock**](http://www.tcpweb.com.br/JS-Clock/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('some-selector').jsclock();
});
```